# Trait Type Parameter Not Recognised In Method

Tags: scala

I have this mock example of a problem I am facing.

```scala
class Baz[-A](
) {
  def p: Unit = println("hi")
}

def n[A](b: Baz[A]): Unit = b.p

trait Foo[R[_] <: Baz[_]] {

  def m[A](req: R[A]): Unit = {
    n(req)
  }

}
```

I get this compile time error

```scala
no type parameters for method n: (b: Baz[A])Unit exist so that it can be applied to arguments (R[A])
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
found   : R[A]
required: Baz[?A]
n(req)
```

I was expecting that because I have specified the super type for `R[_]` to be `Baz[_]` passing a value of type `R[_]` to a method that requires a `Baz[A]` would resolve but the compiler doesn't seem to think so. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: You problem that `A` is not `Int`. Try `def m(req: R[Int])`

Comment: sorry I updated the question - now it shows the problem correctly. I don't understand why the compiler can't understand why R[A] is not a subtype of Baz[A]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `R[_] <: Baz[_]` doesn't mean what you think it does.
It just implies that there should be a class `R` that is a subclass of `Baz`, which is different from saying that  `R[x]` is a subtype of `Baz[x]` for any type `x`; which is what you want.

Thankfully, the language does provide a way to imply that, in a very similar way: `R[x] <: Baz[x]` that fixes the problem.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/pfH0XsvXTSOgN63nvtXb9w/12)*.